# Querying in SQL-

Tags: sql-server

I have a table named "Results" like below:

[image]

I'd like to count personnel who have been completely scored. It means the ones who have no zero in score column. For example based on the uploaded picture just person with ID 1004 should be counted and the outcome should be one.
I used this code:

```
select Count(PrsID) from results 
where Score <> 0
group by PrsID
```

But it wouldn't help me cause if a person has just one non-zero score, he will be counted!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
select PrsID, Count(1) from results 
where Score = 0
group by PrsID
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, but unfortunately it didn't work for me...It counts every one who has at least one non-zero score.

Comment: Changed to count 0 instead of non 0

Answer (score 0):

This one returns count of person who has non zero score

```
SELECT 
    t1.PrsID,
    Count(t1.PrsID)
FROM
(   SELECT 
      * 
    FROM results 
    GROUP BY results.PrsID
    ORDER BY results.Score ASC
) AS t1
WHERE t1.Score <> 0;
```

Comment: Thanks Kemal, but unfortunately it didn't work for me...It counts every one who has at least one non-zero score.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation as below:

```
Select PrsId from results
    group by PrsId
    having sum(case when score = 0 then 1 else 0 end) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think a little change is necessary as followed:    ...having sum(case when score = 0 then 0 else 1 end) > 1    Thank you dear Kannan, very helpful.

Comment: Your solution lists PrsIDs which is very nice but does not count  them.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I think this is what you want: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(PrsID)) FROM results WHERE PrsID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT PrsID FROM results WHERE score = 0)`

Comment: You've answered it very very well,Thanks a thousand dear Kemal.

Comment: Sorry for mistaking the name dear infiniteuniverse. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. If one of the answers has solved your problem, you should accept it to help others who may have a similar question. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry for late answer, how can I do as you said (accept the answer)? My reputation is less than 15 :(  !

Answer (score 0):

If a person's min score is greater than zero, then they should be counted.

```
select count(1)
from (
        select PrsID 
        from results 
        group by PrsID
        having min(Score) > 0) as results
```